# if statement: 'fi' unexpected

Tags: shell-script, busybox

I have made a shell with an if statment, all newline characters are LF (Linux), when i try to execute the shell, i get an "syntax error: 'fi' unexpected".

```
if [ "$(ls -A /storage/$SDCARD_DIR/Android/obb/*/)" ]; then
    echo -n -e $Y'One of games folders on your external SDCard has been already moved\n\nTo fix that:\n- We back to main menu\n- Select rs option to restore a specifiq game file in your internal storage\n- Try again to the ma option to move all your games files to your external sdcard'$N
    clear && main_menu
else
    echo -n -e $C"For info: it's necessary to forcing games apps to be closed"$N; sleep 8;

   APPSNAMES=`for dirs in "$INTFOLD"; do printf '%s\n' $dirs | sed -r -e 's/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Android\/obb\///' | awk -f. '{print $NF}' | sed -r -e 's/\///'`
   while printf '%s\n' "$APPSNAMES" | while IFS= read -r line
    do
        if [ -z $(ps | grep "$line") ]; then
            xargs kill
            echo -n -e $Y'Game(s) app(s) has been closed\nReady for next step...'$N; sleep 4;
        else
            echo -n -e $C'No game run in background on your device\nNext step now..'$N; sleep 4;
        fi
   done

   echo -n -e $B'Move all your games to your external SCard...'$N; sleep 5;
   for D in `find /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/ -maxdepth 1 -type d`
    do cp -af $D $EXSDCARD
   done
   for F in `find /storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/ -type f`
    do rm -f $F
   done
   for X in `find "$EXSDCARD" -type F`
    do ln -s $X $EXSDCARD
   done
   echo -n -e $G'All OBB files are now moved to your sdcard\nNB: You could even see files in your internal storage, but they are just linked\n'$N; sleep 7;
   echo -n -e $B'Back to main menu...'$N; sleep 5;
main_menu
fi
```

I don't understand why i get this error, i would like to point out that i use this script on Android environment with Termux, Busybox and got root access.

I have already check several threads of users with the same issue but i don't find any error(s).

Comment: See the double `while` in `while printf '%s\n' "$APPSNAMES" | while IFS= read -r line`, only one of which has a corresponding `do`/`done`.

Comment: yet another plug for shellcheck.net

Comment: When assigning to `APPSNAMES` you use a `for` loop.  This loop is never closed.  Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697

Comment: There are a total of five `do` in the code, but only four `done`. At the same time, there are six `for` or `while`.

Comment: Thank you very much StéphaneChazelas , thanks Jeff Schaller for the website and Kusalananda for his fixs, effectivly some of my loops didn't have their done.

Comment: Paste your code into http://shellcheck.net for help with syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

The only think I don't like (can see is wrong) is

```
 while printf '%s\n' "$APPSNAMES" | while IFS= read -r line
```

Two whiles and only one do+done

Comment: The `for dirs in "$INTFOLD"` also has no `done`